# How to call CTE within Select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

How to call a CTE within `Select` query in SQL Server? I'm facing issue on how to call CTE within the select query, below query is not executed.

I have 5 different kinds of stored procedure as like below, I'm executing these 5 stored procedures inside one stored procedure. The problem When executing each 5 stored procedures sepeartely, they are working fine. When executing those 5 stored procedures from inside one "master" stored procedure, I'm facing issue. The Inidividual stored procedure results (like query) as a parameter of common stored procedure.

My stored procedure:

```
SELECT 5 AS Count,
(
       ;WITH CTE (Name,CountValue,Title,DisplayOrder) AS
(
     SELECT
            JS.Name , 
            COUNT(JA.JobId) CountValue,
            DB.Name AS Title,
            DB.DisplayOrder 
       FROM JobAction_TBL JA WITH (NOLOCK) 
 INNER JOIN JobActionStatus_TBL JS WITH (NOLOCK) 
         ON JS.ActionCode = JA.ActionCode 
        AND JA.IsDeleted = 0 
 INNER JOIN JobHeader_TBL AS JH WITH (NOLOCK) 
         ON JH.Id = JA.JobId 
        AND JH.IsDeleted=0
 INNER JOIN UserInOrganizationMas_TBL AS UO WITH (NOLOCK) 
         ON UO.OrganizationId = JH.OrganizationId
 INNER JOIN DashboardItems_TBL AS DB WITH (NOLOCK) 
         ON DB.SpName='JobstatusReport_SP'
--WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CONVERT(DATETIME,JA.ActionedDate,101),101) = '06/18/2018'
   GROUP BY JS.NAME,DB.Name,DB.DisplayOrder
        ) 
  SELECT Name, CountValue,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CountValue * 100 /
                     (SELECT SUM(CountValue) 
                        FROM CTE)
                      ) + '%' AS CountPer ,Title,DisplayOrder
                        FROM CTE
FOR XML PATH ('JobStatusList'), ROOT ('JobStatusReport'), TYPE)

FOR XML PATH ('Dashboard'), ROOT ('Dashboard'), TYPE
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Some databases require that the CTEs occur before the first `SELECT`, which I assume is your syntax error.  You could probably also simplify the query for this question.

Comment: Looks like you also have a wayward `;` before your `WITH`. `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginninator". It's goes at the end of you statement, not at the start, and certainly not in the middle of it. you don't start a `WITH` with a `;` (thus `;WITH`), you **terminate**  your previous statement with a `;`. I assume that someone taught you that you start a `WITH` with `;`, and that's why it's in the middle of your statement. Such advice is wrong.

Comment: Also, what is your reason for using `NOLOCK` everywhere? You know what that does, right? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: If you have to use nolock, you can apply it to the whole procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Make another CTE for the intermediary results and call it instead.

```
;with CTE (Name, CountValue, Title, DisplayOrder) as
(
  select
    JS.Name
    ,count(JA.JobId) as CountValue
    ,DB.Name as Title
    ,DB.DisplayOrder
  from
    JobAction_TBL JA with (nolock)
  join
    JobActionStatus_TBL JS with (nolock)
    on JS.ActionCode = JA.ActionCode
       and JA.IsDeleted = 0
  join
    JobHeader_TBL as JH with (nolock)
    on JH.Id = JA.JobId
       and JH.IsDeleted = 0
  join
    UserInOrganizationMas_TBL as UO with (nolock)
    on UO.OrganizationId = JH.OrganizationId
  join
    DashboardItems_TBL as DB with (nolock)
    on DB.SpName = 'JobstatusReport_SP'
  group by
    JS.NAME
    ,DB.Name
    ,DB.DisplayOrder
)
,CTE2 as
(
  select
    Name
    ,CountValue
    ,convert(varchar(10), CountValue * 100 / (select sum(CountValue) from CTE)) + '%' as CountPer
    ,Title
    ,DisplayOrder
  from
    CTE
)

-- CALL THE CTE's
```

Comment: I have 5 different kinds of Stored Procedure as like above, I'm executing these  5 Storeprocedure inside one StoredProcedure. The problem When executing each 5 storedProcedure sepeartely, it's working fine. when executing 5 StoredProcedure inside One StoredProcedure that time I'm facing issue. The Inidividual StoredProcedure result(Like Query) as a parameter of Common StoredProcedure.

Comment: In SQL Server we generally work with "sets" of results. If problem solving becomes complex then, moving set generation into Views and CTEs is common (as above). Writing large and complex SQL commands can sometimes be efficiently implemented by the optimiser but sometimes not. When spreading work across multiple SP's, consider using temporary tables (e.g. ##MyTable) to share these data sets more easily